FileNotFoundException thrown only for .mp3s but not for .png
I'm developing a game in Swing, where I'd like to use both audio and image assets. My issue is that, while opening the .png images works fine, opening my .mp3 file always throws a FileNotFoundException, and file.exists() returns false.
Nothing seems to work. I've researched the issue, looked at a similar question, played around with adding and removing the '/' from the filePath, changing the mp3 directory, created a new IntelliJ project, restarted my PC, and tried opening a .wav file instead, with no success.
Here's a simplified version of my code, where I try to read an image Baker.png successfully, and read an audio file QuestOfLegends.mp3 unsuccessfully.
Main.java
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String imagePath = "/images/Baker.png";
        String audioPath = "/audio/QuestOfLegends.mp3";

        System.out.println("The absolute path of this class is: " + new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("The audio package is a directory?: " + new File("/audio").isDirectory());
        System.out.println("The images package is a directory?: " + new File("/images").isDirectory());

        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getResource(imagePath)));
            System.out.println("Image read successful.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Image read failed.");
        }
        try {
            File file = new File(audioPath);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                throw new Exception("File does not exit at "+ audioPath);
            } else {
                AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInput);
                clip.start();
                clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Read failed");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Here's my directory hierarchy.
I tried using:
File file = new File(Main.class.getResource("/audio/QuestOfLegends.mp3")); 

and I still got the same error.

maybe because the used build system (IDE, Maven, Gradle, ...) does not consider .mp3 files as being resources and consequently does not copy these from the source folder to the build folder. Usually the code does not run in the src folder (the so called working directory,) so it does not search files in src.

There once was a thing about path handling, where relative and absolute paths sing... Please try this: new File(getClass().getRessource("/audio/QuestOfLegends.mp3"));

@user85421 The output of new File(".").getAbsolutePath() is C:\Users\...\Testing\., where Testing is my IntelliJ project folder.

@user85421 What do you mean by "the  audio folder must also be is some directory given in the classpath."? I use getResource for reading an image: BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getResource(imagePath))); and it is successful. However, I use File file = new File(audioPath); to open the audio file.

I meant "must be in some directory" - as I wrote, the resource files are searched by the exact same way as the  .class files. So the audio directory must be also found on one of the directories listed on the classpath (valid only if using getResource*(), but now I've  seen that code is using file = new File(audioPath) - disregard the classpath -  check the result of file.toAbsolutePath() (despite using File and getResource is kind of confusing/inconsistent [unless you really know what these are doing])

since using new File("/audio/...") the audio directory must be in the root directory! If using new File("audio/...") the audio directory must be in C:\Users\...\Testing\  (since that was the output of new File(".").toAbsolutePath())

Using File file = new File(Main.class.getResource("/audio/QuestOfLegends.mp3")); is wrong! It should be
InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/audio/QuestOfLegends.mp3");

Resources are deployed along with your app, generally inside a jar, so they are no longer files in the file system.
The below illustrates this, plus some additional observations on the original code:
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String imagePath = "/images/Baker.png";
        String audioPath = "/audio/QuestOfLegends.wav"; // MP3 is not supported out of the box

        System.out.println("The absolute path of this class is: " + "Wherever it was compiled to");
        System.out.println("The audio package is a directory?: " + "No - it's a resource folder");
        System.out.println("The images package is a directory?: " + "No - it's a resource folder");

        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getResource(imagePath)));
            System.out.println("Image read successful.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Image read failed.");
        }
        try (InputStream in = Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(audioPath))) {
            AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInput);
            clip.start();
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            // Clip will start in its own thread so prevent the main thread from exiting right away
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Read failed");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

